# Extract patient from an CT

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 3d, mfc, vtk

It is possible to extract the patient only from an CT, without mass (without mass where patient was lay down in order to exposed for CT) ? There is something VTK filter that could be used for this task ?

Comment: You patients have no mass?  What?

Comment: Thank you for your attention ... when I wrote mass, I meant "bed", the bed where the patient lay down while it take CT ...

Answer (score 1):

under some conditions it is possible to segment patient object from CT bed based on region growing segmentation. there is no class in VTK for this kind o segmentation. you can try ConnectedThresholdImageFilter in ITK or implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: I will search some examples about ConnectedThresholdImageFilter ... did you use it by now this object ? Have you isolate the patient only (without the bed) with this ?

Comment: yes I've used this class and it was useful. in some cases it failed to separate the patient automatically which was because of the noisy condition of image.

Comment: Ok, thank you ... these 2 examples is good to apply for this task ? From here you taken the model ? http://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Broken/Images/ConnectedThresholdImageFilter and http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/Examples_2Segmentation_2ConnectedThresholdImageFilter_8cxx-example.html ?

Comment: I used it a long time ago. I don't remember how I made it right. but the examples are OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is vtkImageSeedConnectivity which is a basic region growing algorithm in VTK.
You'll probably need to preprocess the data before to use it

Comment: Simon, kindly thank you for your post, I have searched an example of using vtkImageSeedConnectivity ... I Only found this: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/ClipArt, I don't know how it help ... Could you elaborate a little bit of what preprocess I should make before I use vtkImageSeedConnectivity ? Flaviu.

Comment: Well, what you are trying to do is a 3D segmentation task, not that easy ;)
By pre-processing I meant for example smooth the data to simplify the segmentation task, using a [Gaussian smoothing](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/ImageGaussianSmooth) or anisotropic filtering.
After that you will need to actually detect one or more seed point which are "inside" the region you want to extract (the bed). So for example iterate along a line from the "floor" to the "sky" and try to catch the pixel representing the bed ... 
And finally you'll need to adjust the two thresholds !

Comment: I have succeed into applying anisotropic filter on my volume (taken by vtkDICOMImageFilter), and now I am trying to iterate the volume from "floor" to "sky" (I guess iterate by X coordinates), but is there a method to know which proprieties has the "bed" point ?